# How are HSA contribution limits calculated when filing taxes jointly?

Tags: united-states, contribution, hsa, limits

My wife and I both have HSA accounts, which we intend to max out.
We are not dependents on either's accounts not any other dependents in each of the accounts. We also can easily max out the single contributions of $3300.

I know the family limit is $6550 (which is 2*single - 50).

We also intend to file taxes jointly. So what is the total contribution limit for the two us: $6600 (2*single) or $6550?

Does this mean one of us, or both have to scale back a bit from the individual max contributions ?

Comment: You both have separate high deductible health insurance?

Comment: That is correct. Both of us are employed and have medical insurance from workplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this link](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p969/ar02.html#en_US_2012_publink1000204045), if you both have individual coverage, you can both contribute $3300 for a total of $6600. If one of you had family coverage for the other, they could contribute $6550, but then the other could not contribute anything.

> For 2013, if you have self-only HDHP coverage, you can contribute up
>   to $3,250. If you have family HDHP coverage you can contribute up to
>   $6,450.

Note the limits haven't been updated for 2014 in this document yet.

Answer (score 1):

since the difference is only $50, i'd suggest to remain on safe side and use $6550 as the limit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a  confusion in this matter with the IRS ?